# The TOC tree, linking pages with "Next" and "Previous" buttons

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

Im having a problem with the "Next" and "previous" buttons that connect my pages.

Im using reStructuredText with Sphinx
http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/toctree.html

I think the problem has something to do with a "Toctree"

Here is my site
http://missionimpossible3000.org/Glossary_Word_Definitions/index.html

when you click "Next" on the bottom of the page
It goes to the contribute page.
Thats fine.

But when you click on "previous" while on the Contribute page,
it skips the glossary page.

Answer (score 0):

nevermind, I just had to refresh the contribute page...